# How to loop a task in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, twitch, twitch-api

I am experimenting with making my own little discord bot that can get information from Twitch, but I'm stumped on how to make the bot loop and check for a condition.

I want the bot to loop a section of code every few seconds that checks if the specified twitch channel is live.

---

**Code**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from twitch import TwitchClient
from pprint import pformat


client = TwitchClient(client_id='<twitch token>')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

@bot.command()
async def info(ctx, username):
    response = await ctx.send("Querying twitch database...")
    try:
        users = client.users.translate_usernames_to_ids(username)
        for user in users:
            print(user.id)
            userid = user.id
        twitchinfo = client.users.get_by_id(userid)
        status = client.streams.get_stream_by_user(userid)
        if status == None:
            print("Not live")
            livestat = twitchinfo.display_name + "is not live"
        else:
            livestat = twitchinfo.display_name + " is " + status.stream_type
        responsemsg = pformat(twitchinfo) + "\n" + livestat
        await response.edit(content=responsemsg)
    except:
        await response.edit(content="Invalid username")

bot.run("<discord token>")
```

---

I want the bot to run the following code every 10 seconds, for example:

```
status = client.streams.get_stream_by_user(<channel id>)
if status == None:
     print("Not live")
     livestat = twitchinfo.display_name + "is not live"
else:
     livestat = twitchinfo.display_name + " is " + status.stream_type
```

---

I've tried using `@tasks.loop(seconds=10)` to try and make a custom `async def` repeat every 10 seconds but it didn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done like so:

```py
async def my_task(ctx, username):
    while True:
        # do something
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

@client.command()
async def info(ctx, username):
    client.loop.create_task(my_task(ctx, username))
```

---

**References:**

- [`asyncio.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task)
- [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep)

Comment: How would i go about breaking this loop?

Comment: [loop.stop()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.stop) could do the trick.

Answer (score 29):

The newer version of `discord.py` doesn't support `client.command()`

To achieve the same I used the following snippet

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks
```

```
client = discord.Client()
```

```
@tasks.loop(seconds = 10) # repeat after every 10 seconds
async def myLoop():
    # work


myLoop.start()

client.run('<your token>')
```

Comment: for the myLoop.start() line I get the error : `RuntimeError: no running event loop`
`sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop._loop' was never awaited`

Comment: @Brendon this is because all awaits need to happen inside an async function. Put `myLoop.start()` inside the async `on_ready` function and it'll work.

Answer (score 6):

This is the most proper way to implement background tasks.

```py
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

bot = commands.Bot(...)

@bot.listen()
async def on_ready():
    task_loop.start() # important to start the loop

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def task_loop():
    ... # this code will be executed every 10 seconds after the bot is ready
```

Check [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) for more info

Comment: You know why this happens?

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'start'

Comment: Seems like you didn't decorate your function or decorated it in a wrong way @OldSport

Comment: This solution fit right into my problem. TY!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this as well. The problem I ran into is that none of the examples online were complete. Here is one I came up with that uses `@tasks.loop(seconds=10)`.

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import tasks
from dotenv import load_dotenv

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
CHANNEL_ID = 1234

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"We have logged in as {client.user}")
    myloop.start()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user: 
        return

    if message.content.startswith("hi"):
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def myloop():
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send("Message")

client.run(token)
```