# CLOSED Discord.py rewrite with async

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

This code changes the discord bot's status every 10 seconds. Code worked before I pip updated discord.py, but now it gives an error: Someone told me, to create a `main` function and inside that function put, `await ch_pr()`?

> then you need to sue `asyncio.run` to run the funtion

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\Frecker\testbot.py", line 160, in <module>
    client.loop.create_task(ch_pr())
  File "C:\Users\Londo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 108, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(msg)
AttributeError: loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts. Consider using either an asynchronous main function and passing it to asyncio.run or using asynchronous initialisation hooks such as Client.setup_hook
```

Code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ipc_error(self,endpoint, error):
    print(endpoint, "raised", error)

async def ch_pr():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    statuses = [
        discord.Game(name=f"on {len(client.guilds)} servers! | >help"),
        discord.Game(name="discord.py"),
        discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.streaming, name="ChezLondo on Youtube", url="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCE8aHxOOXspTeC0Lm5vx2KA"),
        discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.streaming, name="ChezLondo_ on Twitch", url="https://www.twitch.tv/chezlondo_"),
        discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="Freker on top.gg!"),
        discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="over you fools")
    ]
    while not client.is_closed():
        status = random.choice(statuses)
        await client.change_presence(activity=status)

        await asyncio.sleep(10)

client.loop.create_task(ch_pr())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920560/how-to-loop-a-task-in-discord-py Maybe this could help you?

Answer (score 0):

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds = 10)
async def task_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    statuses = [
        discord.Game(name=f"on {len(client.guilds)} servers! | >help"),
        discord.Game(name="discord.py"),
        discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.streaming, name="ChezLondo on Youtube", url="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCE8aHxOOXspTeC0Lm5vx2KA"),
        discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.streaming, name="ChezLondo_ on Twitch", url="https://www.twitch.tv/chezlondo_"),
        discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="Freker on top.gg!"),
        discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="over you fools")
    ]
    while not client.is_closed():
        status = random.choice(statuses)
        await client.change_presence(activity=status)

        await asyncio.sleep(10)

#client.loop.create_task(ch_pr())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logging in as ")
#   sleep(3)
    print(client.user.name)
    print("Freker, are we ready?")
    print("Sir yes sir")
    Beep(700 , 500)
    Beep(1000 , 500)
    channel = client.get_channel(994315757175451830) 
    await channel.send("Hi, I'm back online!")
    task_loop.start()
```