# How to send a message using discord.py into a channel without input but on true condition

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, client

here is my code i'm trying to integrate with a script that runs 24/7

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(3534536365654654)
    await channel.send("Bot is ready")


@client.event
async def background_task():
    channel = client.get_channel(3534536365654654)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Testing")
    embed.add_field(name="Req Amount", value="100")
    embed.add_field(name="Return Amount", value="120")
    await channel.send(embed=embed)

client.run(token)
```

basically every time my condition sets to true in the main code i want to run background_task()
in the main file but right now while running just this code only the on_ready() function is sending an output.

My bot is not supposed to take any inputs or commands just send the message each time the condition is true in code.

I've also tested all previous solutions and they have been rendered useless after the async update to discord.py

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920560/how-to-loop-a-task-in-discord-py

Answer (score 0):

Use [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) and just have it run every few minutes (or hours/whatever) and check that the condition you want is True - if it is then send the message you want to send.

The `@client.event` syntax is usually reserved for actual client events - so `background_task` is never going to be executed.

Comment: ahh yes your answer combined with the comment above works perfectly, create a task loop for background_task() and use background_task.start() in on_ready()

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in to [`discord.ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#discord-ext-tasks-asyncio-task-helpers)

Here's a simple example which executes every 5 seconds. With every loop you can check on a value and perform the actions accordingly.

```
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
async def bg_task(self):
    if value:
        // Do something on True
    else:
        // Do something on False
```

Then start the `task` like this:

```
bg_task.start()
```

Comment: this generates the function for me but it still doesn't give an output unfortunately

Comment: I missed the part where you start the loop, I have updated the answer. Go through docs for better understanding of `tasks` in `discord.py`